# Trying to do bitwise AND with two ints in Java, but the compiler tries to use them as bools

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Here's a function I wrote in C++ (which works) and am now trying to convert to Java:

```
static String parseAInstruction(String line) {
    int n = getValue(line);
    if (n>=0) {
        String inst = "0";
        for (int i=14; i>=0; --i) {
            if (Math.pow(2, i) & n)
                inst += "1";
            else
                inst += "0";
        }
        return inst;
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

This compiles just fine in C++, but when trying to compile in Java, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean

    at parser.Parser.parseAInstruction(Parser.java:38)
    at parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:50)
```

Looking up bitwise AND in Java, it seems that it should be the same. It shouldn't have anything to do with booleans at all. Can anyone tell me the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java you can only use boolean values in `if` clauses.  So the result of a bitwise AND of two numbers is not valid in an `if` statement.

Try this instead: `if ((Math.pow(2, i) & n) != 0) {`.

**[Edit]** However, as commenter @jlordo points out, next you'll have to resolve the problem of doing a bitwise AND between a double and an integer.

Comment: This will result in a compiler error: `The operator & is undefined for the argument type(s) double, int`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you can't just use an integer in the conditon expression for `if`.  you need something like:

```
        if (((int)Math.pow(2, i) & n) != 0)
```

Comment: True.  Fixed.  It's interesting that the OP didn't mention this compile error, though.

Comment: In OPs code the compiler sees the `&` and assumes there is an `int` in the condition and complains `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean` just like OP wrote.

Comment: Originally I had a self-written function in place of pow which returned an int instead of a double, so that's why. Anyway I guess I was used to C/C++ where you could use ints in if statements. It makes sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
if (Math.pow(2, i) & n)
```

In Java, you need to have a `boolean` value as a condition. You probably want:

```
if (((int)(Math.pow(2, i)) & n) != 0)
```

The cast to `int` is necessary because `Math.pow()` will return a `double` and the `&` operator is only defined for two `int` operands.

Answer (score 1):

> Trying to do bitwise AND with two ints in Java, but the compiler tries to use them as bools

No it doesn't. The result of the bitwise AND is of type `int`. Java requires the expression in an `if` statement to be of type boolean, and yours isn't. You need to convert the expression to boolean.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.pow` in Java is calculated with a logarithm and an exponentiation (unlike C++, where the compiler often optimizes calls to `pow`), both very slow, approximate, floating point operations.

It doesn't even make sense to use here - you're working with bits, so work with bits:

`(n & (1 << i)) != 0` is what you're looking for.